# Count each value in a column within the column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, count

I am struggling to do the below and was wondering if you can help me.

I have a pandas data frame of 2 columns. I want to count each value in column A within Column A. If the occurrence is more than 1, print('hello')

For instance,

`for i in range(1, len(DF))
    **if count(DF.iloc[[i],[1]].values)>1:**
        print('hello')`
any help please?

Thanks,
H

Comment: I think you mean, that for each value in Column A you want to check, if it exists in column B, right?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to print 'hello' if there is more than one occurence:**

```
if (df['A'] > 1).count() > 1:
    print('hello')
```

**If you want to print 'hello' at each occurence:**

You could use `df.apply()` to apply a printing lambda function to your column:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: print('hello') if x > 1 else None)
```

Or count all values in A which are greater than one and print in a loop:

```
for i in range(0, (df['A'] > 1).count()):
    print('hello')
```

Comment: But you are counting values greater than one and print accordingly, the question however was to print, if a value occurs more than once, not if a value greater 1 occurs.

Comment: Hello Jurgen,Thanks a lot for your help. I get an exception error when I run `for i in range(0, (df['A'] > 1).count()):
    print('hello')` Can you please help? This is my code below `PSE0=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PSE_DES,str(Sht1['K4'].value)),delimiter='\t')
PSE0=pd.DataFrame(PSE0,columns=['EFFECTIVE DATE','RIC','CHANGE TYPE','SEQ NUM'])
for i in range(0, (PSE0['A'] > 1).count()):
    print(str(i))`

Comment: Just to be clearer, I want to loop over each value in the column of the dataframe PSE0, and if duplicate within the same column, print('Hello'). "Actually I dont want to print hello, but i will do other operations."

Comment: @Hassanov what exception are you having?
So you want to loop over the values, and take action on the specific row if you encounter a duplicate? - IE - do you need to take into consideration your row's values if you encounter your duplicate or just need to take an action regarding of the number of duplicates and regardless the other columns?

Comment: @Jurgen, exactly as you said, I want to loop over values and take action on the specific row if I encounter a duplicate.I am sorry, i wasnot clear about this.

Comment: Any help with this dilemma guys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

if you want to print once hello if there is any value that is repeated use:

```
if df['A'].value_counts().gt(1).any():
    print('hello')
```

if you want to print hello for each value in the series that is repeated:

```
print('Hello\n'*df['A'].map(df['A'].value_counts().gt(1)).sum())
```

---

if you want to print hello for each **unique** value in the series that is repeated

```
print('Hello\n'*df['A'].value_counts().gt(1).sum())
```

---

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,4,4,5,7,8,9,3]})
print(df)

    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   4
5   4
6   5
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  3

if df['A'].value_counts().gt(1).any():
    print('hello\n')
print('2 Method\n')    
print('Hello\n'*df['A'].map(df['A'].value_counts().gt(1)).sum())
print('3 Method\n')
print('Hello\n'*df['A'].value_counts().gt(1).sum())
```

**Output**

```
hello

2 Method

Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

3 Method

Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to loop over the values, and take action on the specific row if I encounter a duplicate. Do you have a solution for this? Sorry if I wasnt clear about it in my original post.

Comment: Please find below 'PSE0=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(PSE_DES,str(Sht1['K4'].value)),delimiter='\t') PSE0=pd.DataFrame(PSE0,columns=['EFFECTIVE DATE','RIC','CHANGE TYPE','SEQ NUM']) for i in range(0, (PSE0['A'] > 1).count()): print(str(i))' Ideally, i will drop the entire row if it is NOT duplicate. but not to complicate things, I just need to perform operations on the row itself. So it has to be in the same code structure I gave you above. I searched around but no one had this case.